# Primefaces xml,pdf data export is not working

Tags: xml, jsf, pdf, primefaces, data-export

I m using primefaces 3.5 and want to export my datatable as pdf or xml. I don't get any error but it doesn't work. When i clicked the button, page just refreshes itself. Also i added poi-3.9.jar and itextpdf but i got same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title> Cem Yeniçeri</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="AraçBilgileriPaneli2">
            <p:graphicImage id="savronik_image" value="/savronik.png" width="500" height="150"/>
            <p:panel id="panel" header="Araç Bilgileri">
                <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="5" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Araç Seçiniz : "/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{json_vehicle.arac_id}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Seçilen Aracın Bilgilerini Getir"
                                     actionListener="#{json_vehicle.aracBilgileriniYukle(actionEvent)}" update="datatbl"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Tüm Araçların Bilgilerini Getir"
                                          actionListener="#{json_vehicle.aracBilgileriniYukle2(actionEvent)}" update="datatbl"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Tablo Sil"
                                     actionListener="#{json_vehicle.tabloSil(actionEvent)}" update="datatbl"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:messages id="messages3" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
            </p:panel>
            <br/><br/>
            <p:dataTable id ="datatbl" var="v"  value="#{json_vehicle.vehicles}">
                <p:column headerText="Araç No">
                    <h:outputText value="#{v.vehicle_id}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Araç Adı">
                    <h:outputText value="#{v.vehicle_name}"  />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Tarih">
                    <h:outputText value="#{v.record_date}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Araç Sahibi">
                    <h:outputText value="#{v.owner}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Araç Tipi">
                    <h:outputText value="#{v.vehicle_type}"  />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Tahsis Yeri">
                    <h:outputText value="#{v.allocated_region}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:panel header="Export All Data">
            <h:commandLink>
                <p:graphicImage value="xml.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="datatbl" fileName="myxml" />
            </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage value="pdf.png" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="datatbl" fileName="mypdf" />
                </h:commandLink>
        </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am having same problem..No error in Log, but still `<p:dataExporter>` is not working! :(

Answer (score 2):

try to use this dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

or download it manually if u don't use maven.
additionally, make sure you use 'ajax=false' property in p:commandLink.

Comment: In case this helps someone, I also needed to download the Apache Commons Math 3.6.1  dependency to get things to work. Also along with ajax="false" property I also added immediate="true" property in the p:commandButton. My project didn't have Maven, so I copy pasted the poi-5.0.0 & commons-math3-3.6.1 jar files directly into my projects "WEB-INF/lib" folder

Comment: @Ghos3t, Commons Math was probably needed for another need in your project. My project already had itextpdf and POI, and just add the "ajax = false" that my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. You must ajax=false. And I suggess primefaces commandlink but this is optional.

```
  <p:commandLink ajax="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="xml.png" />
            <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="datatbl" fileName="myxml" />
   </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: I added ajax="false" property but unfortunately same issue.

Comment: i changed it as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this; **immediate="true"**

```
   <p:commandLink ajax="false" immediate="true">
                <p:graphicImage value="xml.png" />
                <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="datatbl" fileName="myxml" />
   </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that your problem is in commandLink, try this:

```
<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage value="resources/path/to/your/icon.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="datatbl" fileName="data_table" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Why is this a good answer? Don't see the advantage of switching from `p:commandLink ajax="false"` to an `h:commandLink`